# Form submit button in AJAX loaded jQuery pop up not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Evening,

I've read a few other threads relating to this issue but still I am unable to resolve it.

I have a 'report' button on a webpage which when clicked brings up a pop up box with jQuery which displays another page via AJAX. This works fine.

The problem is: the submit button won't work. Strangly, it does seem to work on iOS Safari but won't work on desktop broswers.

The form has 3 radio buttons and a textarea, when the user clicks the submit button it should send the values to a PHP page receiving them and confirmation that the form has been submitted to be displayed in the AJAX page without reloading anything.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXr2M/) of the set up.

Any ideas?

Comment: As a side-note: In your fiddle you have no reference to jQuery. Your HTML is invalid as well: `<label><input type="radio" name="reportchoice" value="3" /><p>3</label></p>` Place your closing `</label>` in front of the `<p>` tag or after the `</p>` tag. Also, just in-case, `<p>` tags within `<label>` seems to fail validation here: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: I just threw that together quickly to illustrate the set up, it's not a copy and paste of the code. Apologies for mistakes.

Comment: So do you wish to send the form or not? Either you send the values through an AJAX request to a PHP file, or you just send the form with the submit button, if you need the first option, just add the property `onsubmit="return false;"` in the `form` element

Answer (score 2):

In Your fiddle example You used:

```
var queryString = $('#reportform').formSerialize();
```

You should use:

```
var queryString = $('#reportform').serialize();
```

There is no formSerialize() method in jQuery.